# Queries: Using multiple columns with same name but from different tables as conditions for the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-server-2014, querying

I want to use SOME_DATE and ANOTHER_DATE columns from different tables as part of the conditions for the `WHERE` clause of my query.

I can only get it to work if I remove `AND ATT.[SOME_DATE] <= '02 december 2020' AND ATT.[ANOTHER_DATE] >= '02 december 2020'` from the query below:

```
;WITH cs AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        t.LKJ_UID,
        t.ITEM_UID,
        t.[I_T_UID], 
        t.[I_I_CD], 
        t.[L_DS], 
        t.[SOME_DATE], 
        t.[ANOTHER_DATE], 
        t.[AN_DATED], 
        t.[LS_E_DATE], 
        t.[LS_E_UST_UID], 
        t.[PTU_UID], 
        t.[FMT_UID], 
        t.[DG_LT], 
        t.[DG_A], 
        t.[OD], 
        t.[NTH], 
        t.[BJU], 
        t.[BJI], 
        t.[LOK], 
        t.[JUT], 
        ATT.[FG_UID], 
        ATT.[RTU_UID], 
        ATT.[LKJ_CD], 
        ATT.[LKJ_NAME], 
        ATT.[LKJ_TYPE_UID], 
        ATT.[LKJ_LENGTH], 
        ATT.[LCA_KIP_UID], 
        ATT.[CL_WD], 
        ATT.[LCA_OCC_LC_UID], 
        ATT.[SJ_K], 
        ATT.[SJ_J],
        ATT.SOME_DATE as SA_SOME_DATE,
        ATT.ANOTHER_DATE as SA_ANOTHER_DATE
       
    FROM 
        CATT AS t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        ATT ON t.LKJ_uid = ATT.LKJ_uid
    
    WHERE 
        t.[SOME_DATE] <= '02 december 2020'
        AND t.[ANOTHER_DATE] >= '02 december 2020'
        AND ATT.[SOME_DATE] <= '02 december 2020'
        AND ATT.[ANOTHER_DATE] >= '02 december 2020'

    ORDER BY t.[ITEM_UID]
        OFFSET 24 * 0 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT 24 ROWS ONLY
) 

SELECT *
FROM cs
ORDER BY 
cs.ITEM_UID
```

Only if I remove this part of the last example will it work, but I need it to obey all 4 conditions, not just the two:

```
AND ATT.[SOME_DATE] <= '02 december 2020'
AND ATT.[ANOTHER_DATE] >= '02 december 2020'
```

Thank you for your help

EDIT: (in response to Shawnt00's answer)

This query returns 72k rows, whereas the changes you suggested return 1.6 million records:

```
SELECT dbo.CATT.*, 
       dbo.ATT.* 
FROM   dbo.CATT 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ATT 
               ON dbo.CATT.LKJ_uid = 
                  dbo.ATT.LKJ_uid 
WHERE  ( dbo.CATT.SOME_DATE <= 
         CONVERT(DATETIME, '02 december 2020' 
                , 
                102) ) 
       AND ( dbo.CATT.ANOTHER_DATE >= 
             CONVERT(DATETIME, '02 december 2020', 
                 102) ) 
       AND ( dbo.ATT.SOME_DATE <= 
             CONVERT(DATETIME, '02 december 2020', 
                 102) ) 
       AND ( dbo.ATT.ANOTHER_DATE >= 
             CONVERT(DATETIME, '02 december 2020', 
             102) )
```

Comment: Couple things: <1> "_executes forever_" sounds like a performance problem. How large is your data set and are there any indexes available? <2> Your queries are quite different from each other, not sure if comparing the performance makes sense, the troublesome version has (1) extra paging with `offset` and `fetch next` clauses, (2) no date conversion for `02 december 2020`, (3) extra CTE construction and (4) extra sorting with an `order by` clause outside the CTE... <3> The `left join` from the last version is an _implicite_ `inner join` due to the ranges on that table in the `where` clause.

Comment: @Sander there are 72k records with all four WHERE conditions applied. If I remove the the last two WHERE conditions (which makes the second query work) there are 1.6 million records. I'm not entirely convinced it's a performance problem due to the fact that if I remove the two WHERE conditions from the second query, the query just works, even with the additional paging, CTE etc. . (explained in original post)

Comment: @NickyLarson what do you mean by "work"-- does it throw an error? does it run for a long time without completing?

Comment: surely performance is going be imminent I think start_date  and end_date must be indexed also add filter to exclude start_date  or end_date where null ex. `start_date  not null and end_date  not null`

Comment: order by kills the whole system, try running without order by and see the results  - NOTE: As a general rule, doing CASTs or CONVERTs on items in your SELECT clause cost almost nothing.  (Note that CASTs or CONVERTs in WHERE or ON clauses can be very expensive since they will keep SQL Server from making effective use of indexes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the condition into the join. Remove it from `where`.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        section_attributes ON t.section_uid = section_attributes.section_uid
    AND SECTION_ATTRIBUTES.START_DATE <= '02 december 2020'
    AND SECTION_ATTRIBUTES.END_DATE >= '02 december 2020'
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Would you mind explaining why the condition cannot remain in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: I spoke too soon. The changes you suggested return 1.6 million records, whereas if I run the query that I just added to my original post under "EDIT" it returns 72k results. (what it should be returning)

Comment: Why are you using an outer join?

Comment: I've just received confirmation that it needs to be an Outer Join because it should not matter if there are no records in the joining table. In that case the answer is correct and it should indeed return 1.6 million records. Apologies